# Decomposing a $\mathbb Z[i]$-module using Smith normal form

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let V be a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module generated by elements $v_1$ and $v_2$ with the following relations:

$$
(1+i)v_1+(2-i)v_2=0
$$
and
$$
3v_1+5iv_2=0
$$

I need to write V as a sum of cyclic modules.
I tried to do this the basic way: putting the matrix
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}1+i&2-i\\3&5i
\end{array}
\right]
$$
in the Smith form
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&-11+8i
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Now, by the Structure Theorem, we have that $V$ is isomorphic to $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{\langle 3-19i\rangle}$, which is cyclic because $\langle 3-19i\rangle$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Therefore nothing more needs to be done.

Is that correct?

Comment: Dear Gustavo, I think there is an error in your computations.  E.g. the determinant of the original matrix is $-11 + 8i$, which is not the same as $3 - 19i$ (even up to a unit).  Regards,

Comment: Ok, I'm going to make my calculations again. Regardless, can you tell me if the idea is correct?

Comment: Dear Gustavo, Yes, the idea is correct.  Regards,

Comment: I made my calculations again, I noticed that in one particular step I was multiplying a row by a factor which was not an unit (in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$); now the result is the matrix $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&-11+8i\end{array}\right]$$ just as you pointed through the determinant. Thus the result is that V is isomorphic to $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[1]}{<-11+8i>}$. Thanks!

Comment: Dear Gustavo, You're welcome.  I am writing an answer reflecting our exchange in the comments, just so that this question can move from the *unanswered* to the *answered* category.  Best wishes,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer, based on the discussion in the comments:

The method is correct, but there was a calculation mistake.  The correct answer
is that the module $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[i]/\langle -11 + 8i \rangle.$